# Populating blank columns with polygon information

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table

I have two layers in QGIS 2.8.2: a point layer and a polygon layer. Points fall within different polygons. Polygons have identifying features (ID, Name). Point layer has a blank column in the attribute table. I would like to populate the blank column with information from the polygon layer (Name). I tried relating the two layers (as described [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#n-relation)), but that only allows me to see the relation if I click on a point and does not actually populate the blank column.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You probably should use `Join attributes by location`. Then you could copy attributes from added column to existing one. Be sure your layers have the same CRS.

Comment: I tried Join attributes by location (with target layer as the point layer and join layer as the polygon layer), but the resulting layer comes up as empty (0 features). It does warn that they have non-matching CRSs, but I made sure they were both in EPSG:4326, WGS 84 before running. I did both "take attributes of first located feature" and "take summary of intersecting feature", even though the second option doesn't make a lot of sense given that the attribute I'm interested in is not a numerical one ("Name"). I also did "Keep all records."

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! The best way to do this is Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect
This will combine the attribute tables!